# How to Convert UTC Time To User's Local Time in Django

Tags: django, timezone

I undrestand that this question is repeated, but unfortunately I cannot find any answer.

My impression is that Django already takes care of converting server time to local user as long as I have

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_TZ = True
```

in my settings.

Even more if the db is [postgresql](http://As%20a%20consequence,%20if%20you%E2%80%99re%20using%20PostgreSQL,%20you%20can%20switch%20between%20USE_TZ%20=%20False%20and%20USE_TZ%20=%20True%20freely.%20The%20database%20connection%E2%80%99s%20time%20zone%20will%20be%20set%20to%20TIME_ZONE%20or%20UTC%20respectively,%20so%20that%20Django%20obtains%20correct%20datetimes%20in%20all%20cases.%20You%20don%E2%80%99t%20need%20to%20perform%20any%20data%20conversions.) that setting also doesn't matter and every thing will be still converted.

however I tried all the followings:

```
{% load tz %}
{{ obj.date }}
{{ obj.date|localtime }}
{{ obj.date | timezone:"Canada/Mountain" }}
```

and only last one works and the rest gives me UTC time. Last one also is not useful as the time would be only correct for users in that zone.

I was wondering if I am missing anything here.

I have a very simple test model:

```
class TimeObject(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My impression is that Django already takes care of converting server time to local

Unfortunately that is incorrect.

As discussed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone), there's no automatic way of knowing what the user's timezone is. You need to figure that out in some other way (it could be saved as a user setting, for example). Then you need to [`activate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone) that timezone. Once you do, Django will perform the conversion.

Comment: where would be the best place to `activate()` local timezone in a Django Project globally?

Comment: @NabatFarsi: That depends on how you're determining the user's time zone, but one good way is to do it in middleware, as shown in the linked documentation.