# Reading the time zone of the end-user in Django

Tags: javascript, django

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65174060/how-to-convert-utc-time-to-users-local-time-in-django) apparently there is no way to read time zone of the end-user in Django. different methods all will read time zone of the server, rather than end user.

I see that in javascript the following code will give time zone of the user and not server:

```
const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
```

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659523/how-to-get-the-exact-local-time-of-client) which my test confirmed that.

now my question is where would be the cleanest place to run the above code in a Django project which perhaps will be followed by an Ajax call to `Activate()` timezone.

Answer (score 0):

In your template before calling your Ajax function.